# Flash - eval() available?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there any way to execute arbitrary code in Flash, like javascript's eval()?

I'd like to take some code as a string and execute it, if possible (I understand this is not a great idea),

Thanks

Comment: Trivia tidbit: there used to be a native eval() function in AS2, but it's been removed in AS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eval() function is not part of AS3, but apparently you can hack together something like that:

http://eval.hurlant.com/demo/#app=da4a&757d-selectedIndex=0

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the **D.eval** library, which allows you to execute a limited set of statements.

http://www.riaone.com/products/deval/index.html